# Flutter Padding EdgeInsets fromLTRB pushes the content to the bottom

Tags: flutter, dart, padding

I am trying to add *bottom padding* to my *Column* inside of the *Card* widget (refer to picture and code below):
[![snapshot of my code and layout][1]][1]

Code:

```
Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 10, 20)),
                  Text('${e.phrase}', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white60),),
                  Divider(height: 5, color: Colors.transparent,),
                  Text('${e.author}', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white60),)
                ],
              ),
```

Problem: The more I increase the bottom padding value, the more the content of the column is pushed to the bottom, which is the opposite of what is intended, what am I doing wrong? Please explain.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dFKKt.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wanna set padding for Column widget do it this way

```
Padding(
    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 10, 20),
    child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
            Text('quotes'),
            Text('quotes author')
        ],
    ),
),
```

you passed a Padding widget as a child of Column, thus you just got an empty box as sibling of Text Widget.

[image]

if you look into the documentation or source code of Padding widget you'll see that Padding widget accept an optional child widget.

```
class Padding extends SingleChildRenderObjectWidget {
const Padding({
    Key key,
    @required this.padding,
    Widget child,
}) : assert(padding != null),
    super(key: key, child: child);

final EdgeInsetsGeometry padding;

... // other code omitted
}
```

so if you wanna set padding for the container Column, you should make it child of Padding widget.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it wrong. You need to wrap the column inside a Container and then add the margin.

```
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 10, 20),//Add Margin here
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(
                        '${e.phrase}',
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white60),
                      ),
                      Divider(
                        height: 5,
                        color: Colors.transparent,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        '${e.author}',
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white60),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
```

Comment: Could you please explain what is happening in my code?

Comment: I mean, the other attributes, like the ```Top``` value, work as intended except for the ```Bottom``` one.

Comment: Passing a padding as a child in the column will just create an empty box inside the column, it wont work for the other children

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap Padding with Column.

[image: flutter padding androidride]

```
Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(50.0),
      child: Text('Text Widget'),
    ),
```

[For more information](https://androidride.com/flutter-padding-widget/)